# What does a scale attached to an Atwood machine measure?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

Assuming a massless and frictionless pulley with two arbitrary masses, what is it that the scale actually measures of the system?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show a picture of how the scale is connected to the device.

Comment: If it is hooked to the pulley it will measure 2T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the scale is attached to the pulley then it is measuring the force $F$ that is supporting the pulley.

Considering the weights and pulley as a single system, the external forces acting on the system are $F$ and its total weight $W$ - the tension in the rope $T$ is an internal force and can be ignored. But note that the system is *not* in equilibrium. Since the heavier weight is descending while the lighter weight is raised, the centre of mass of the system is accelerating downwards with some acceleration $a$. So if the total mass of the system is $M$ we have

$W - F = Ma \\ \Rightarrow F = W-Ma < W$

Alternatively, as noted in one of the comments, you can consider the forces acting on the pulley alone (which *is* in equilibrium) and conclude that

$F=2T$

Comment: How come the force acting on the pulley is $2T$ rather than $T$?

Comment: @StannisBa In the standard Atwood machine the rope wraps half way around the pulley. Each half of the rope exerts a force $T$ downwards on the pulley, so the total tension force on the pulley is $2T$, and the net force on the pulley is $F-2T$, which must be zero. If this isn't clear, draw a free body diagram for the pulley.